# Visual Studio Installer Project 2017 - Unrecoverable Build Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am having an issue rebuilding a multi-project solution that contains an installer project. I keep getting the error: `ERROR: Unrecoverable build error`

I have scoured Google and this site and have tried the following, with no success;

1. Repairing VS
2. Repairing SSDT
3. Uninstalling SSDT
4. Registering both mergemod.dll and ole32.dll after closing VS and then rebuilding

If anyone has not been able to solve this issue using the above methods, I'd love to hear about it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue yesterday (but with VS 2008). I did the following 3 steps and it fixed the issue:

1. Register the DLL mergemod.dll (regsvr32.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll)
2. Register the DLL ole32.dll (regsvr32.exe ole32.dll)
3. Delete the cache/temporary visual studio files – which get generated as part of the builds. (C:\users{BUILD_USER}\appdata\local\temp).

Hope that helps!